# Passing info between WebApiApplication & ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

Trying to build in some additional logging to my WebAPI system. Using the lifecycle info for IIS requests, I've been able to logging code by using Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest in Global.asax.cs.

However there are actions within a request (ie: database activity) which happen within my ApiControllers that I want to log as well.

In the BeginRequest, I am able to access the HttpContext.Items to store info to be retrieved in EndRequest. However, this doesn't appear to be available in an ApiController.

I attempted to use the Request.Headers object to do this. But I guess since one is a HttpRequest and the other is HttpRequestMessage, they don't share a common memory location.

I thought to make a collection object static in Global, and store info that way. But since it's static, wouldn't allow for cross-pollination between requests?

**EDIT: tried this and confirmed, static data is shared between requests

It's possible to use an external datastore to do this, but seems like this should be able to be accomplished right within IIS.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't think of this earlier, but I just added an entry to the Request headers, as that's available everywhere.

So in my Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        // this is avaiable in Global.asax - not ApiControllers
        Context.Items.Add("request_start_time", DateTime.Now);
        // this is avaiable everywhere
        Request.Headers.Add("Request_Key", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
```